# How to map TreeSet value to a TreeMap?

Tags: java, java-stream, treemap, treeset

I Have  `TreeSet set` which has some values .
I want to map each element in the `set` with specific value to be a map using streams .
that for example if the `set` contains `{1,2,3}` and the `value=5 ;`
so I want the map be like this

```
1->5
2->5
3->5
```

The problem that I do not know what to write in the map function part

```
TreeMap<Integer,Integer> map = set.stream().map(x-> ????).collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeMap:: new )) ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `map`, use `Collectors.toMap()`:

```
TreeMap<Integer,Integer> map = 
    set.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),i -> 5,(a,b)->a,TreeMap::new));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do that :

```
TreeMap<Integer,Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
set.forEach(v-> map.put(v, 5));
```